# SQL error in FROM clause: near ')' when using query code in view

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a fairly simple query that converts image to varcharmax.

```
SELECT 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + Signature as SignatureAsText
FROM openjson((select Signature from dbo.[Daily Activity Attendance] for json auto)) 
WITH (Signature varchar(max))
```

It works fine in query but throws error upon saving in view. The view actually works it seems but designer can't handle it. I want to integrate it into larger view definition but want to make sure it cleanly works stand alone first.

Comment: Can you post the `create view`

Comment: What do you mean by "designer"?   Are you using a GUI?

Comment: Sorry designer was wrong word I meant Management Studio. I am choosing Create View and pasting my code into SQL Pane. When I attempt to save the view I get the error message.